# How to get dynamic IQueryable type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, kendo-grid, entity, iqueryable

I have code like this in a base class which the type of its derived class is known. I would like to know if it is possible to apply `IQueryable<DerivedType>`.

I would like to know if I could switch out `XXX` for the type of class known by my `EntityType` variable.  How could this be done with the result of picking the right entity table from `dbEntities`

**BaseClass.cs**

```
protected abstract Type EntityType {get;}

public virtual DataSourceResult populate([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{

    using (var dbEntities = new dbEntities())
    { 
        IQueryable<XXX> entityResult = dbEntities.XXX;
        DataSourceResult result = entityResult.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Example:
I want to get a `IQueryAble<>` of the type `Type EntityType` and also have to pick this type from `dbEntities`. So say I have a table in `dbEntities` called `giraffe` which is inherited from `animal`. Then the current code above belongs to the `animal` base class. `EntityTpe` knows that `EntityType.Name` is equal to giraffe. So I would the the with XXX to output in equivalence to `IQueryable<giraffe> entityResult = dbEntities.giraffe`

Comment: Yes, you can substitute XXXX for any class implementing XXXX if that's your question

Comment: Kind of, I want to get a `IQueryAble<>` of the type `Type EntityType` and also have to pick this type from `dbEntities`. So say I have a table in `dbEntities` called `giraffe` which is inherited from `animal`. Then the current code belongs to the `animal` base class. `EntityTpe` knows that `EntityType.Name` is equal to giraffe. So I would the the with XXX to output in equivalence to `IQueryable<giraffe> entityResult = dbEntities.giraffe`

Comment: Yes, you can do that, the entity is still a POCO .NET class

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics for this. You will also need to use the `DbSet<T>` property of your context. Something like this should do:

```
public virtual DataSourceResult populate<T>([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{

    using (var dbEntities = new dbEntities())
    { 
        IQueryable<T> entityResult = dbEntities.DbSet<T>();
        DataSourceResult result = entityResult.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = populate<MyEntity>(request);
```

Comment: My `dbEntites` does not have the `DbSet<>()` method, is this a problem?

Comment: Well we have no idea what your `dbEntities` type is.

Comment: So its a model of an `.edmx` file that inherits from `ObjectContext`

Comment: You may be able to use `ObjectSet<T>` instead